# Downloading GraalVM Ideal Graph Visualizer

Tags: git, path, graalvm

I went through the process of setting up the Ideal Graph Visualizer from https://www.graalvm.org/latest/tools/igv/ and I was able to download the mx and graal repositories but when I try to launch the IGV using `mx -p graal/compiler igv`, it says the filename is too long. I have already set LongPathsEnabled to 1 in the Registry Editor.

````
WARNING: symlinking not supported
Consider flag -J-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2 if on a high resolution display
Consider flag -J-Xms4g -J-Xmx8g if dealing with large graphs
Error executing: C:\Users\drobi\.mx\cache\IDEALGRAPHVISUALIZER-0_31-0A82D7A0D60_DIST_20a3d87927fbecfe9b61dcd6c59f12f4c25e7da1ca926ea6d2571594424782751261e581e1c6e5113aeaeb8f31b8141b1941f7bbef1c6c07c55b9a753812b6db\idealgraphvisualizer-0-31-0a82d7a0d60-dist.extracted\idealgraphvisualizer\bin\idealgraphvisualizer.exe --jdkhome C:\Users\drobi\.jdks\graalvm-jdk-21.0.1+12.1 "-J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=false"
[WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long```
````

Comment: try to run those commands from [git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) if it does not work then try [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) or real ubuntu/debian.

Answer (score 0):

So it's clear that this is because the filename is too long for Windows to handle, which happens because `mx` downloads IdealGraphVisualizer into `~\.mx\cache\IDEALGRAPHVISUALIZER-0_31-0A82D7A0D60_DIST_20a3d87927fbecfe9b61dcd6c59f12f4c25e7da1ca926ea6d2571594424782751261e581e1c6e5113aeaeb8f31b8141b1941f7bbef1c6c07c55b9a753812b6db` which - after appending the directory to the .exe file - becomes a path longer than 260. I tried inserting some code using `ctypes` to convert the path into a ShortPath usable by Windows, which works...

But then the .exe file for IGV (which naturally can't be edited simply) uses it's path (which would be in short format) and plays with it, adding a `.clusters` file to it - where the short format version should be `.CLU`. Meaning the resultant path is of an illegal mixed form, and so the program crashes.

The easiest workaround therefore is changing the folder name in the cache (e.g. change it to `IDEALGRAPHVISUALIZER`) and editing the `run_netbeans_app` function on line 67 in the file `PATH_TO_GRAAL_DIRECTORY\graal\compiler\mx.compiler\mx_graal_tools.py`. Line 75 should be changed from `extractPath = res.get_path(resolve=True)` to

```
if app_name == 'IdealGraphVisualizer':
        extractPath = 'PATH_TO_MX\\.mx\\cache\\IDEALGRAPHVISUALIZER\\idealgraphvisualizer-0-31-0a82d7a0d60-dist.extracted'
    else:
        extractPath = res.get_path(resolve=True)
```

On my system this works perfectly, and is quick to implement - no need to chase around mx.py files/functions. The `PATH_TO_GRAAL_DIRECTORY` would be the directory which you initially called `git clone https://github.com/oracle/graal.git` (probably the same directory that `mx` is located).